# Microsoft Office 2016, how to import SVG?

Tags: svg, ms-office

I just updated my MS Office 2016 to version 16.0.8067.2115 ([which is the latest version if I'm correct](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mt465751.aspx)).

I read [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-SVG-images-in-Microsoft-Office-69f29d39-194a-4072-8c35-dbe5e7ea528c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) that the latest version supposedly has support for using SVG files.

However, I am unable to insert any svg file into any office program (using Insert > Picture from the ribbon or by dragging a file into an office program).

Am I doing something wrong? Does this version of Office not actually support SVG files? Or is there some setting that I missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question here: https://www.msoutlook.info/question/office-update-channels

Apparently, new updates like the ability to use SVG files are solely available for Office 365 subscribers and not for people who bought a one-time licence for Office 2016 (as I did).

Comment: It's supported now in "one-time licence for Office 2016".

Comment: @ShadowWarrior is this also true for one-time *volume* licenses? I am on PowerPoint 2016 v16.0.4266.1001 with a POWERPNT.EXE last modified in 2015 despite installing all Windows and Microsoft updates regularly.

Comment: Well I just bought the Microsoft 365 version of Word (and the other apps) and it accepted one rather small svg file but the for another it says "The picture can't be displayed."